# Create array of React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you create an array of React elements eg something like:

```
const Component = () => {

  const myArray = [{<p>Hi</p>}]

  return(
    // Stuff
  )
}
```

Comment: yes  without curlyBrackets

Comment: The React documentation explains this in the [JSX in depth part](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
const myArray = [<p>1</p>, <p>2</p>, <p>3</p>];

// Fragment is included because everything in return needs to be wrapped in a single tag
return (
    <Fragment>{ myArray }</Fragment>
)
```

Also note that `{`'s are used to embed logic inside JSX

```
const foo1 = 'foo';
const foo2 = 'bar';
const myArray = [<p>{foo1}</p>, <p>{foo2}</p>];

return (
    <Fragment>
        {myArray.map((item, index) => (
            <span key={index}>
               <h1>{ 'Element #' + index }</h1>
               {item}
            </span>
        )}
    </Fragment>
)
```